# Azure Document DB UpdateDoc

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am starting off with azure document db. I was trying to update an existing document.  When I use the following query everything works:

```
dynamic Team2Doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink).Where(d => d.Id == "t002").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
Team2Doc.TeamName = "UPDATED_TEAM_2";
await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(Team2Doc);
```

but if use the below code:

```
dynamic Team2Doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink).Where(d => d.TeamName== "team1").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
Team2Doc.TeamName = "UPDATED_TEAM_2";
await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(Team2Doc);
```

I get this error:

> "The best overloaded method match for
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions)' has some invalid
>   arguments"

Is there anyway to retrieve a document by one of the properties and update the document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The where clause is trying to query the property `TeamName` which does not exist in `Document` class.

Changing  the type of the queryable to your data model should fix it.

For example, say you have the following data model:

```
public class EmployeeDocument : Document
{   
     // Other properties that you may have similarly defined ....

     public class string TeamName 
     {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue<string>("TeamName");
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue("TeamName", value);
        }
     }
}
```

Then you can modify your query like this:

```
var team2Doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<EmployeeDocument>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink).Where(d => d.TeamName== "team1").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
team2Doc.TeamName = "UPDATED_TEAM_2";
await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(team2Doc);
```

Note that you have to use the EmployeeDocument, instead of the Document class, while creating the document queryable. That will let you query on EmployeeDocument properties.

**SQL Version**

Creating a document model for each of your existing data models may not be feasible if you have a large number of data models. In that case you may want to try out the SQL query syntax.

[Refer to Aravind's answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29571538/802799). The example he uses is for deleting documents, but it can be easily modified to update them too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a model with Id:

```
public class Employee
{            
     [JsonPropery("id")]
     public class string Id { get; set; }

     public class string TeamName { get; set; }
}
```

And then replace the document using it's Id:

```
var employee= client
    .CreateDocumentQuery<Employee>(documentCollection.DocumentsLink)
    .Where(d => d.TeamName== "team1")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault();

employee.TeamName = "team2";

var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, employee.Id);

await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(employee);
```

Comment: hmm. i don't think this works. `Employee` isn't of type `Document` so how can you call `ReplaceDocumentAsync()` as it's document. Also, simply calling `employee.TeamName = "team2";` doesn't invalidate the document so it won't update.